# 2D Map Editor Tiles Palette - Best suited Java Elements to use?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm making a 2D RTS Map Editor and here came the moment to make a Palette which is just a popup frame showing tiles to be clicked on and then applied on the map.

I'm wondering which Java Elements to use for this palette?
At the moment I have set a JFrame which will contain Jlabels which have their Icon set as some ImageIcon (which are the tiles of my game).
(I have a `List<ImageIcon> tiles` which contains every tiles)

```
mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(tiles.size() / 2, 2, 5,5));
    JLabel tilePanel;

    for (int i = 0; i < tiles.size() ; i++) {
        tilePanel = new JLabel();
        tilePanel.setIcon(tiles.get(i));
        mainFrame.add(tilePanel);
    }
```

Here's what I have:

[image: JFrame with JLabels Icon set as my Tiles]

However, I want to be able to click on these JLabels to be selected and so that I can use a function like `getSelectedTile` in my main JFrame to place them on the Map. But adding a mouseListener/Event to each and every JLabel doesn't seem right.

**My questions are:**

- Am I going the right way? If so, how should listen to my JLabels to know which tile is selected.
- What SHOULD I use if this isn't the way to go?

Thanks in advance! All suggestions will be taken into consideration :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I want to be able to click on these JLabels to

You an use a JButton instead of a JLabel. You can make the button look like a label by using:

```
JButton button = new JButton(...);
button.setBorderPainted( false );
button.setContentAreaFilled( false );
button.setFocusPainted( false );
```

Then you add an `ActionListener` to the button to handle the clicking of the button.

Comment: But if I have in the 70 tiles afterwards, I'll have to set 70 Jbuttons with 70 Listeners?

Comment: Yes you would use a loop to create the buttons. You only need one listener. You use the `getSource()` method of the ActionEvent to get the button that was clicked.